# Is it permitted to water one's flowers during the 9 days?

Tags: nine-days

Is it permitted to water one's flowers during the 9 days?  Or is this not permitted?  What is the halacha here?  Let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Mi Yodeya! According to the sefer [Peninei Halacha](https://www.sefaria.org/Peninei_Halakhah%2C_Zemanim.8.16.5?lang=bi) (a resource I highly recommend) it is no problem.

> Similarly, one may not plant anything that brings joy, like decorative trees, hedges, or flowers (SA 551:2). **However, one may maintain a decorative garden, water the garden, mow the lawn, and continue regular maintenance.**

Comment: (Assuming one is not in Israel this year)

Comment: @JoelK Shmittah is a whole different topic.

Answer (score 0):

Rav Simcha Bunim Cohen writes in [Laws of Daily Living: Three Weeks, Tishah B'Av, and Other Fasts](https://www.artscroll.com/Books-Viewinsides/9781422609071.html) (5:C:1):

"Regular upkeep of previously planted trees, gardens, etc. is permitted (e.g., weeding, watering, and mowing the lawn.)"